# WordPress Settings API Saving Bootstrap Multiselect Field using Selected Function

Tags: php, wordpress, multi-select, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm having issues with saving on a multi-select field on a custom settings page for a plugin I'm creating. Seemingly even before bootstrap, the multi-select field will save 1 value from the field, but on selecting 2 it will not save both options.

I've tried the usual slinging `[]` onto the end of the name but that doesn't seem to work likely because it's already sat in an array one would assume but I'm stumped on why it's not saving when 2 values are selected.

Code to follow:

```
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'settings_Init' );
    function settings_Init() { 

        register_setting( 
            'Plugin_Settings', //A settings group name. Should correspond to an allowed option key name.
            'Plugin_Settings_Sanitize' //The name of an option to sanitize and save.
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'Plugin_Settings_Section', //$id 
            __( 'Settings', 'textdomain' ), //$title
            'Settings_Section_Callback', //Function that echos out any content at the top of the section (between heading and fields).
            'Plugin_Settings' //The slug-name of the settings page on which to show the section
        );

        add_settings_field( 
            'Select_Field', 
            __( 'Directory', 'textdomain' ), 
            'Render_Select', 
            'Plugin_Settings', 
            'Plugin_Settings_Section' 
        );
    }


    function Settings_Section_Callback(  ) { 
        echo __( 'This below options must be configured to ensure the plugin works as expected.', 'textdomain' );
    }


    function Render_Select() { 
        $options = get_option( 'Plugin_Settings_Sanitize' );
        $products = wc_get_products(array(
            'type' => 'course',
            'status' => 'published',
            'limit' => -1,
        ));?>
        
            <select class="" name='Plugin_Settings_Sanitize[Select_Field]' multiple>
                <?php foreach($products as $product){?>
                    <option value='<?php echo $product->get_id();?>' <?php selected($options['Select_Field'], $product->get_id());?>>
                        <?php echo $product->get_title();?>
                    </option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        <?php
    }

    function options_page(  ) { ?>
        <form action='options.php' method='post'>
            <h2>Platform</h2>
            <?php var_dump($_POST);?>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>
            <?php settings_fields( 'Plugin_Settings' ); 
            do_settings_sections( 'Plugin_Settings' ); 
            submit_button();?>
        </form>
    <?php }
```

For purpose of frontend, the rendered options are as follows:

```
    <select class="" name="Plugin_Settings_Sanitize[Select_Field]" multiple="">
        <option value="17">This is a course test (Copy)</option>
        <option value="14" selected="selected">This is a course test</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: try to serialize the data from select and save it use update_option(), then for the frontend part, unserialize the data and verify if value exist in array for check the selected option

Comment: **For purpose of frontend** Can you please clarify, are you using `options_page` in frontend to show the form? or did you hook the function as an admin menu page callback? Currently, your given code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code.

You'll have to fix that select HTML page. here is the explanation and new version `Render_Select` function.

#### CHANGELOG:

- Change `Plugin_Settings_Sanitize[Select_Field]` to `Plugin_Settings_Sanitize[]`, if you are trying to store other settings fields in `Plugin_Settings_Sanitize` and Want to save Product ids in `Select_Field` key then use `Plugin_Settings_Sanitize[Select_Field][]`
- change `selected($options['Select_Field'], $product->get_id())` to `selected( in_array( absint( $product->get_id() ), $selected_ids, true ), true )` 
  where `$selected_ids` is an array if selected product ids. 
  as you'll store ids in array then `selected` function won't work with the array. so we'll have to check `true === true` in selected function. for that, we'll check if the current product id in the loop is available in saved values. 
  if it's available in the array then true otherwise false, then use that true/false within the selected function. on top of that, I am mapping the options values array with `absint` so that we can do the strict comparison with `===`

```php
function Render_Select() {
    // Get the options while passing empty array as default value.
    $options = get_option( 'Plugin_Settings_Sanitize', array() );

    // Check if options is empty and Select_Field key exists and it's data is not empty.
    // then converting the type to array using (array), because we want to make sure we have an array
    // then we map it with absint function using array_map function so that we have integer
    // not string that we are going to use for strict comparison.
    $selected_ids = ! empty( $options ) && isset( $options['Select_Field'] ) && ! empty( $options['Select_Field'] ) ? array_map( 'absint', (array) $options['Select_Field'] ) : array();

    // Fetch the product array.
    $products = wc_get_products(
        array(
            'type'   => 'course',
            'status' => 'published',
            'limit'  => -1,
        )
    );

    ?>
    <select class="" name='Plugin_Settings_Sanitize[Select_Field][]' multiple>
        <?php
        /**
         * Explanation of this code
         * selected( in_array( absint( $product->get_id() ), $selected_ids, true ), true )
         *
         * $is_selected  = in_array( absint( $product->get_id() ), $selected_ids, true ); // check if product id is in selected ids.
         * selected( $is_selected, true ); // check if is selected is true, if true write selected="selected" by function.
         */
        ?>
        <?php foreach ( $products as $product ) { ?>
            <option value='<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>' <?php selected( in_array( absint( $product->get_id() ), $selected_ids, true ), true ); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html( $product->get_title() ); ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Hi, there following error comes back ```Warning: array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given``` and for extra context I chose the ```Plugin_Settings_Sanitize[Select_Field][]``` choice you provided. If I remove the selected code the 2 Options I expect to appear as Options appear just fine.

Comment: `$selected_ids = empty( $options ) ? [] : array_map( 'absint', $options );` we can perform empty check before map like this.

Comment: Feel free to update your answer and I'll mark yours as the answer with bounty as its cleaner code than mine

Comment: @DanielVickers I have updated the code. Now I performing extra checks on `$selected_ids` array and I have defined it on top.